# Visual studio C++ Copy obj file instead of compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio, caching, compilation

In team, we have many type of PC, we use the strongest one to build project. When the other PC build, it takes too much time. Therefore, we think about copying built cpp file, .obj file, so that weak PC don't have to build again. But It seem doesn't work.

I have read this [article](http://itscompiling.eu/2017/02/19/speed-cpp-compilation-compiler-cache/) about compiler cache but I want something that is integrated to Visual studio

Do you guys have any idea, suggestion?

Comment: I do not get what your question is. If you are compiling c++ code one one machine, you can't run it on another machine without recompiling it. The compiler compiles the code specifically for the architecture on which is running. So every time you change machine, you need to recompile your program.

Comment: I do not get what your question is. If you are compiling c++ code one one machine, you can't run it on another machine without recompiling it. The compiler compiles the code specifically for the architecture on which is running. So every time you change machine, you need to recompile your program.

Comment: Sorry for your confusion. I mean with the same source code, I compile cpp files on first machine to obj files, then I copy those cpp files to 2nd machine. Now 2nd machine only have to link those cpp files. But visual studio recompile all and that's not what I want. I know it's weird but if you have any idea?

Comment: @Daniele: That is completely untrue.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but you might look at [Incredibuild](https://www.incredibuild.com/) to see if it could help you solve your build speed issues.

Comment: Move most of the code into static libraries. Create one solution with all project that will be build on the strong machine. And create another solution - that includes only 1 exe project and expects all lib files to be available. Then you can commit your compiled lib files on the strong machine and link them into the exe on the slow machine

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Thanks for suggestion, but we usually modify some code at slow machines or debug we have to build lib anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"something that is integrated to Visual studio"

That would be IncrediBuild, integrated in VS2017.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. But Incredibuild is not free at all. It would be great if there is any free tool or method which we will apply ourselve.

Comment: Indeed, the network functionality isn't free. But the benefit is bigger than you'd think - you can combine CPU power of multiple machines, not just one fast machine.